# How to tag the code of a website for structured data recognition by Google SEO?

Tags: tags, seo, meta

we're just completing a new site build. With the current theme, we have had issues with structured data (we've highlighted it on Webmasters tools, and weeks later had to re-highlight it, and even then the highlighting prediction is not where we would like it to be).

It seems like Google is not able to find our Title, author, categories, content, featured image, date very easily. I'd expect to be able to communicate this to Google with 100% accuracy, since its so simple and we use the same format for all our articles). So maybe our theme is missing something by way of tags or something in the code to point to and identify this data?

Is that the case? Could someone please tell me what this aspect is called (so I can research it by its term), explain what I need to do with the new build, point me in the direction of an authoritative explanation/tutorial?

The site in question is a WordPress site, but I also am working on some php sites and would like to use this information on all sites, if it can be applied this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use micro-data to mark-up the structured data. Also Google will really like your site if you show him (with a code) everything about the site - navigation, sidebar (aside), content (article) and so on. I suggest you to read about schema.org and micro-formats.
Here is an [usefull article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-microdata-to-markup-structured-data) about your problem and how to implement micro-formats to your site.

Comment: Thanks Kasmetski, I read a few articles on Schema and micro-data in my research, but actually the way you phrase it cleared the idea up quite a bit. Thanks for the article. The strange thing I see is that, looking at page sources, other (news) sites don't have these item tags. They just have <meta> title, description, author, etc.